# How to best bucket data to optimize performance of models?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, optimization, modeling

I'm training multiple models to predict churn for customers belonging to online stores. Each model contains customer-level features and data related to n-number of stores. However, we've paid barely any attention when it comes to grouping stores together for the model training. We have roughly 300 different stores each containing roughly 100k - 10M customers.

What's the best way to find the optimal grouping of stores for each model training such that I maximize the f1 score performance? Do I need to subsample and iterate through each combination (note: the data set is imbalanced)? Is it some EDA into SHAP values of each store for its existing model? Or is this something suited to be tackled by like a clustering algorithm (kNN)?

Comment: so it depends on your model.  if you are using a linear model  (eg vowpalwabbit) or neural net you could use embeddings, but ideally you should put in the information yourself- categorising the stores

Comment: @seanv507 I'm using an xgboost model. I agree I should categorize them myself but guess I'm ultimately wondering what is the best way for myself to do this. And my options seem to be 1) brute force train for every combo of stores and see what model performance is like, 2) see if there's some feature that allows me to group stores together, or 3) do a more advanced version of 2) with a clustering approach

Comment: can you not ask someone with any expertise? eg type of product, number of customers,...